# cron job and Long process problem

Tags: python, django, cron

Via django iam launching a thread (via middle ware the moment the first request comes) which continously fetches the twitter public steam and puts it down into the database.Assume the thread name is twitterthread.

I also have have several **cron jobs** which periodically interacts with other third party api services.

**Observed the following Problem:**

if i don't launch *twitterthread* cron jobs are running fine.
Where as if i launch *twitterthread* cron jobs are not running
Any idea on what can go wrong? and any guidelines on the way to fix it.

Comment: There is no connection between python and cron.  I believe you have misdiagnosed your problem, and I don't think you've provided enough information for anyone else to be able to help.  Maybe someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: Yeah i think above is stupid question.After examining the cron error logs i resolve the issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice to avoid launching threads inside the django application. Most of the times you can run the thread as a separate application.

If you deploy the app in a Apache server and you don't control it properly each Apache process will assume that a request is the first one and you could end up with more than one instance of twitterthread.